# why parse exception Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Jan 24 00:00:00 EET 2018

Tags: parseexception

this programe should subtract 2 days tare3 and tare4. tare3 valued from current day (from system) tare4 value from text file (element[3]), when I parsed string (element[3]) to date (tare4) its give`me parseexception 
date saved in file looked like (Thu Jan 24 00:00:00 EET 2018)

```
package javaapplication3;        
import java.io.*;            `     `
import java.util.*;                  
import java.text.*;

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, FileNotFoundException {
    private  static String tare5 = new String();
    static String tare2 = new String ();

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(" dd MMM yyyy  ",Locale.ENGLISH );
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date tare4 =  new Date (); 
    tare5 = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
    Date  tare3 = dateFormat.parse(tare5);

    Scanner scanner;
    File Myfile =  new File("C:\\Users\\mido\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaApplication3\\src\\javaapplication3\\products.txt");
    scanner = new Scanner (Myfile);


    while (scanner.hasNext()){

        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        StringTokenizer x = new StringTokenizer(line,"~");
        String [] element= new String [7]; 
        int counter = 0 ;

        while (x.hasMoreElements())
        {
            element[counter]=(String)x.nextElement();
            counter ++;

        }
        tare4 = dateFormat.parse(element[3]);

        if (tare4.getTime()>= tare3.getTime() )
        {
            System.out.println(element[1]+"is expired");
        }
        else {
            long def = tare3.getTime()- tare4.getTime();
            System.out.println(element[1]+"has"+def+"to expire");}
        }
   }
```

Comment: how can i change this format to 12/8/2000 not names just numbers

Comment: Your question is not clear, please edit it and explain the problem.

Comment: @MrMush done what;s now ?